Dynamic link throwing error in Flutter API Exception 400
My code is throwing the following error and for the life of me I am unable to fix it as I am not able to put a finger on what is causing it...
ERROR:

I/flutter (13998): runZonedGuarded: Caught error in my root zone.
I/flutter (13998): ----------------FIREBASE
CRASHLYTICS---------------- I/flutter (13998):
[firebase_dynamic_links/unknown]
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 400:  I/flutter
(13998): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7) I/flutter
(13998): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18) I/flutter
(13998):  I/flutter (13998): #2
MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:534:43) I/flutter
(13998):  I/flutter (13998): #3
MethodChannelFirebaseDynamicLinks.buildShortLink
(package:firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_dynamic_links.dart:175:11)
I/flutter (13998):  I/flutter (13998): #4
_LoggedInViewState.createDynamicLinkForThisReport (package:auditr/Screens/shareScreen.dart:481:15) I/flutter (13998):
 I/flutter (13998): #5
_LoggedInViewState.getDynamicLink (package:myapp/Screens/shareScreen.dart:466:13) I/flutter (13998):
 I/flutter (13998): #6
_LoggedInViewState._getLink (package:myapp/Screens/shareScreen.dart:461:11) I/flutter (13998):
 I/flutter (13998): #7
_LoggedInViewState.build. (package:myapp/Screens/shareScreen.dart:400:35) I/flutter (13998):
<asynchro I/flutter (13998):

The line which is causing this exception is here:
    Future<Uri?> createDynamicLinkForThisReport(String URL) async {
        late Uri link;
        try {
          final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
            uriPrefix:
                'https://myfirebase.page.link', //'https://eelavan.co.uk/auditrReport',
            link: Uri.parse(URL),
            navigationInfoParameters: const NavigationInfoParameters(
              forcedRedirectEnabled: true,
            ),
          );
            if (kDebugMode) print("Getting short link.....");
          link = (await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(parameters)).shortUrl;// THIS ONE
...

Can someone help please...
